# On an Android device, can I plug a wired microphone and output to bluetooth speakers at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio, microphone

It seems like if my Android phone is connected to a bluetooth speaker and then I plug in a wired microphone through the headphone jack, the bluetooth speaker stops working.

Is there any way to maintain a bluetooth speaker output and yet have functionality from a wired microphone?

I tried a pass-through app called "Mic To Speaker". That works with the phone's on-board microphone in that I can talk into it and the bluetooth speaker will output my voice.
However, as soon as I plug in a wired microphone, the bluetooth speaker output stops.

Answer (score 0):

> However, as soon as I plug in a wired microphone, the bluetooth speaker output stops.

Try changing the output audio path - After connecting to both Bluetooth speaker and wired microphone, locate an UI called Media output then switch it to your Bluetooth speaker. I've attached screenshots I took from an Android 14 device which might look different from yours depending on version of Android.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried doing that and while it technically works, it was unable to maintain an output from two connections at the same time.